# Cannot Make Bootstrap Table Smaller

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, responsive

Need help with an events calendar. There is two issue:

A) Cannot make calendar smaller.
B) Cannot get table-responsive to work.

I tired using height and width on table, but in my test no effects.

```css
.captop {
  caption-side: top;
  padding: 0;
}

.month {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #6e69f5;
  text-align: center;
}

.month ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.month ul li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.month .prev {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.month .next {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#calendar>tbody>tr>td {
  padding: 0;
}

#calendar .card,
#calendar .card-header {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#calendar .active .card-header {
  background: #6e69f5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase text-center">Events</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="table-responsive" id="calDiv">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="calendar">
          <caption class="captop">
            <div class="month">
              <ul>
                <li class="next">❯</li>
                <li>October<br><span style="font-size:18px">2018</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </caption>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Sunday</td>
              <td>Monday</td>
              <td>Tuesday</td>
              <td>Wednesday</td>
              <td>Thursday</td>
              <td>Friday</td>
              <td>Saturday</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">0</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">1</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">2</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">3</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">4</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">5</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">6</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">7</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">8</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">9</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">10</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">11</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">12</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">13</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">14</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">15</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">16</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="active">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">17</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">18</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">19</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">20</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">21</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">22</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">23</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">24</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">25</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">26</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">27</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">28</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">29</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">30</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">31</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code provided is just Bootstrap 4 and HTML. I do have a JavaScript code which is generating the html. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reducing the `font-size` and `padding` along with `@media` of all the elements of your ui, you can achieve that :)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<style>
  .captop {
    caption-side: top;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .month {
    padding: 1rem;
    background: #6e69f5;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .month ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .month ul li {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }
  .month .prev {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  .month .next {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  #calendar>tbody>tr>td {
    padding: 0;
  }
  #calendar .card,
  #calendar .card-header {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  #calendar .active .card-header {
    background: #6e69f5;
  }
  
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    #calendar .card {
      padding: 0;
    }
    .month,
    .table td, .table th,
    #calendar .card-header {
      padding: 4px;
    }
    .card-body {
      padding: 4px !important;
    }
    .month ul li,
    .table td, .table th,
    .h4.card-text.calendar-info {
      font-size: 10px;
    }
    .month ul li span {
      font-size: 10px !important;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase text-center">Events</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="table-responsive" id="calDiv">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="calendar">
          <caption class="captop">
            <div class="month">
              <ul>
                <li class="next">❯</li>
                <li>October<br><span style="font-size:18px">2018</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </caption>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Sunday</td>
              <td>Monday</td>
              <td>Tuesday</td>
              <td>Wednesday</td>
              <td>Thursday</td>
              <td>Friday</td>
              <td>Saturday</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">0</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">1</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">2</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">3</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">4</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">5</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">6</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">7</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">8</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">9</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">10</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">11</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">12</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">13</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">14</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">15</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">16</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="active">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">17</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">18</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">19</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">20</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">21</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">22</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">23</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">24</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">25</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">26</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">27</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">28</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">29</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">30</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header text-right">31</div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of CSS @Media rule for this. Your table is actually already responsive. But because the font size stay static, the div that contains it can't go any smaller which make your table seems not responsive on smaller than 1000px view.

Try this..

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    @media(max-width:991px) {
      #calendar,
      div.card-body>p {
        font-size: smaller;
      }
      #calendar>tbody>tr>td>div>div {
        padding: 5px;
      }
    }
    
    @media(max-width:768px) {
      #calendar,
      div.card-body>p {
        font-size: x-small;
      }
      #calendar>tbody>tr>td>div>div {
        padding: 5px;
      }
    }
    
    @media(max-width:480px) {
      #calendar,
      div.card-body>p {
        font-size: xx-small;
      }
      #calendar>tbody>tr>td>div>div {
        padding: 3px;
      }
    }
    
    @media(max-width:440px) {
      #calendar,
      div.card-body>p {
        font-size: 7.5px;
      }
      #calendar,
      #calendar>tbody>tr>td>div>div {
        padding: 0;
      }
    }
     @media(max-width:390px) {
      #calendar,
      div.card-body>p {
        font-size: 6px;
      }
    }
    
    .captop {
      caption-side: top;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .month {
      padding: 1rem;
      background: #6e69f5;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .month ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    .month ul li {
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
    }
    
    .month .prev {
      float: left;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .month .next {
      float: right;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    #calendar>tbody>tr>td {
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #calendar .card,
    #calendar .card-header {
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    
    #calendar .active .card-header {
      background: #6e69f5;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .as-console-wrapper {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      max-height: 150px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      border-top: 1px solid #000;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .as-console {
      background: #e9e9e9;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    .as-console-row {
      display: table-row;
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
    
    .as-console-row:after {
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 3px 6px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      content: attr(data-date);
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .as-console-row+.as-console-row>* {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    .as-console-row-code {
      width: 100%;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      padding: 3px 5px;
      display: table-cell;
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 13px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .as-console-error:before {
      content: 'Error: ';
      color: #f00;
    }
    
    .as-console-assert:before {
      content: 'Assertion failed: ';
      color: #f00;
    }
    
    .as-console-info:before {
      content: 'Info: ';
      color: #00f;
    }
    
    .as-console-warning:before {
      content: 'Warning: ';
      color: #e90
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes flash {
      0% {
        background: rgba(255, 240, 0, .25);
      }
      100% {
        background: none;
      }
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes flash {
      0% {
        background: rgba(255, 240, 0, .25);
      }
      100% {
        background: none;
      }
    }
    
    @-ms-keyframes flash {
      0% {
        background: rgba(255, 240, 0, .25);
      }
      100% {
        background: none;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes flash {
      0% {
        background: rgba(255, 240, 0, .25);
      }
      100% {
        background: none;
      }
    }
    
    .as-console-row-code,
    .as-console-row:after {
      -webkit-animation: flash 1s;
      -moz-animation: flash 1s;
      -ms-animation: flash 1s;
      animation: flash 1s;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase text-center">Events</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="table-responsive" id="calDiv">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="calendar">
            <caption class="captop">
              <div class="month">
                <ul>
                  <li class="next">❯</li>
                  <li>October<br><span style="font-size:18px">2018</span></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </caption>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Sunday</td>
                <td>Monday</td>
                <td>Tuesday</td>
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td>Thursday</td>
                <td>Friday</td>
                <td>Saturday</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">0</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">1</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">2</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">3</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">4</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">5</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">6</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">7</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">8</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">9</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">10</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">11</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">12</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">13</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">14</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">15</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">16</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="active">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">17</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">18</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">19</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">20</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">21</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">22</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">23</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">24</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">25</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">26</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">27</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">28</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">29</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">30</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">31</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <p class="h4 card-text calendar-info">No Events</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might want to transform ( rotate ) the days of the week to vertical too, on smaller screens.

Comment: Yeah that sounds great too. You may post the answer for that i guess. Thanks @Girisha C for the edit anyway but not much difference that's why I rejected it.

Answer (score 1):

The default table layout is auto, so make it fixed:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```